# smart contract obfuscation

Tags: solidity, tokens

Can anyone assist me in identifying the obfuscation method or tool used for this smart contract?
I've searched everywhere, but I did not find any tool or method for smart contract source code
obfuscator.
link: https://bscscan.com/address/0xFc46B09bf98858B08C5c5DEeb5c19E609FaBD398#code
Thanks for your time.